# Class "smtpTransport" not found

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakeEmail to send mails on my website, below are my config file info

```
public $default = array( 
        'host' => 'smtpout.asia.secureserver.net', 
        'port' => 25, 
        'username' => 'xxxxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxxxx', 
        'transport' => 'smtp',
       // "tls"=>true
    );
```

It is working fine in my local computer but it is giving the below error on godaddy shared hosting.

```
Class "smtpTransport" not found.

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Stack Trace

CORE/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php line 1265 → CakeEmail->transportClass()
CORE/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php line 1133 → CakeEmail->_applyConfig(string)
APP/Controller/AppController.php line 46 → CakeEmail->config(string)
APP/Controller/ServicesController.php line 48 → AppController->sendMail(string, string, string, string, array)
[internal function] → ServicesController->consultnow()
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(ServicesController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 191 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 165 → Dispatcher->_invoke(ServicesController, CakeRequest)
APP/webroot/index.php line 108 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

According to CakePhp's DOC the class is `SmtpTransport`not `smtpTransport`

Autoloader is case sensitive

Reference: http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-SmtpTransport.html

Comment: "_Keep in min class names are case sensative_" - Are you sure about that? But maybe you're right, the autoloader may not include that file (?)

Comment: @Leggendario according to the API the file is located at: Located at `Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php`

Comment: @Leggendario your right the Autoloader isn't picking it up.

Comment: Actually the code is working on local machine but shared hosting has given me this error...although in my implementation I am changing or renaming the SmtpTransport class.

Comment: What os is the local machine? EDIT: if it is windows, windows isn't case sensitive.

Comment: `'smtp'` vs `'Smtp'`, spot the difference. His local filesystem is case-insensitive, so it's most likely either Windows or OS-X

Comment: I am using windows OS and CakePHP version 2.5.5 above all this information I have not changed any class name in Cake package